# Como funciona a herança entre classes no C#?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, classes, herança, uml

Tenho a classe 1 e a classe 2, a classe 2 herda da classe 1.

Outras classes que herdarem da classe 2 herdarão os atributos da classe 1?

Comment: Sim[.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220001/18246)

Comment: Muito obrigado     @LINQ

Comment: Mas imagina aí uma interface e uma classe na estrada. As duas a 80 por hora. Tu acha que fica uma do lado da outra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[O que você chama de atributo na verdade é um campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Herança é um mecanismo de reuso de código, seja algoritmos, seja estrutura de dados. Bem grosso modo a herança faz uma cópia da classe que herdou e cola nessa nova, então tudo o que estava na classe 1 estará na classe 2, portanto se criar uma classe 3 herdando de classe 2, tudo que tem em classe 2 estará em classe 3, incluindo o que já foi copiado de classe 1.

Claro que o mecanismo é um pouco mais complexo do que isso, não é uma cópia de fato, e há mecanismos de proteção de membros, então membros privados da classe 2 ou 1 não serão acessíveis pela classe 3, e um membro protegido em classe 1 precisa continuar pelo menos protegido em classe 2 para que a classe 3 o enxergue. Os membros estão lá, só não podem ser acessados no código das derivadas.

Ainda existe a questão da virtualização, então classe 3 só poderá sobrepor o que for permitido por classe 2, não importa como está em classe 1, ainda que classe 2 não pode dar mais acesso do que ela própria tem.

Pegue o tipo [`Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0). Ele é herdado por todos os tipos de C#, diretamente, mesmo que implicitamente, ou indiretamente porque **o novo tipo herdou de um tipo que já havia herdado de `Object`**. Então `Equals(Object)`, `GetHashCode()`, `GetType()` e `ToString()` estarão disponíveis em todos os tipos escritos em .NET (ok, tem exceções, mas foge da tipagem normal do .NET e do C#).

Note que nele há membros estáticos. Esses membros obviamente não participam da herança, então eles estão fora. Os membros protegidos podem ser acessados pelo tipo derivado, mas não estão disponíveis para acesso fora dele, então eles não são completamente públicos, eles não farão parte do contrato público do tipo derivado, mas eles estão lá. O mesmo vale para os membros privados que nem são documentados, estão presentes no objeto, mas não pode acessá-los de forma normal.

Então é uma hierarquia onde os membros do tipo ascendente sempre estarão presentes nos seus descendentes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).